# Ошибка в vs code ts 1005

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

Подскажите в чем может быть проблема ?
Программа должна выводить возраст в консоли
На просторах интернета проблема встречается, но решения не помогли

```
function calculateAge(year) {
    return 2021 - year
}
function logInfoAbout (name, year) {
const age = calculateAge(year)
if (age > 0) {
    console.log('Человек по имени ' + name + ' сейчас имеет возраст ' + age)
} else {
    console.log('Вообще-то это уже будущее');
}
logInfoAbout(name: 'Андрей', year: 1990)
}
```

**VS code подчёркивает ':' после *name* и пишет Ожидалось ",".ts(1005)**

Консоль выводит следующее:
**app2.js:11 Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list**

Comment: `logInfoAbout('Андрей', 1990)`. И вынесите его из самой функции

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло!

Comment: настоятельно рекомендую начать с изучения JS. TS это не отдельный язык - это надстройка над JS - это официальная позиция команды TS